# How to check for background process in android

Tags: android

In my application I am doing background process of database storing. How can I check that the background process is running or over? using coding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thread status can be checked with `thread.getState()`. You will get [`Thread.State`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.State.html) enum.

Comment: in my application i am not crating the thread...i uses the code in which sys create the thread so how can i know abt thread?